# Load data from a non partition table to partitioned table using DBT incremental model

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to create a dbt model which will fetch data from a non partitioned table (Table A) and insert in a partitioned table (Table B). The data is in Bigquery. On daily basis , all data will be fetched from table A and will be inserted into a new partition in Table B.

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        partition_by = { 'field': 'load_dt', 'data_type': 'date' },
        incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite'
    )
}}


select * from {{ source('Own_Data', 'non_part_bike') }}
```

This one is working fine , but just trying to understand if there is a better approach or any other best practice for this.

Comment: If you are dealing with large tables, using a time-ingestion partition and the option `copy_partitions` can be more cost efficient: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#copying-ingestion-time-partitions

Comment: Thanks for the details . Tried the approach , but facing some issues. 
`
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        partition_by = {  'field': 'load_dt', 'data_type': 'date' ,           'time_ingestion_partitioning': true,  'copy_partitions': true    },
        incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite'
    )
}}

select * from {{ source('Own_Data', 'non_part_bike') }}
`
It is failing with below error : 
BadRequest('PARTITION BY expression must be _PARTITIONDATE, DATE(_PARTITIONTIME), 
`

Load_DT is of datatype DATE in source table (non_part_bike).

Comment: Looks like it will only work for moving data from a partitioned table to a partitioned table .